# Visio Shapesheet Conditional Formula

Tags: formula, visio, shapesheet

I am editing a master shape's shapesheet. I want to adjust the FillForegnd cell in the Fill Format section, which changes the shape's fill color. I want to write a formula for the fill to be one color if Prop.Name contains a certain word (in this case, "Vacant") and otherwise just use the theme color.

I tried this formula just to test the formula, but it did not work. Eventually I'd like to change it to look for whether the cell contains the text rather than equals the text, but in the meantime I couldn't even get this to work. Please advise.

=IF(Prop.Name = "VACANT",THEMEVAL("FillColor",RGB(165,0,0)),THEMEVAL("FillColor",RGB(99,139,173)))

Comment: Note - If there is a way to do this with VBA, I am open to that as well.

Answer (score 1):

For compare strings in ShapeSheet you must use [STRSAME function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/strsame-function).
Please try this syntax
`=IF(STRSAME(Prop.Name,"VACANT"),THEMEVAL("FillColor",RGB(165,0,0)),THEMEVAL("FillColor",RGB(99,139,173)))`

Comment: OP specified if prop contains the keyword, not necessarily an exact match. If that's the condition to fulfill, we can use `LEN(Prop.Name) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Prop.Name,"VACANT","")) > 0`